# Get rows between two date range

Tags: mysql

I have a simple SQL query which will search for matched rows between two date range. Date format to be searched for is 'yyyymm' -> year-month.

I have written the following query but it is giving me error

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE added_on BETWEEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `added_on` )='201606' AND
                       EXTRACT ( YEAR_MONTH FROM `added_on` )='201706'
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '='201606' AND EXTRACT ( YEAR_MONTH FROM `added_on`
>   )='201706' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: `WHERE added_on BETWEEN '201606' AND '201706'`

Comment: it should be dynamic ... 2016-06-08 will be passed by user.i want to extract year-month from the string

Comment: `BETWEEN` can only handle values, not conditions, the latter is what you are trying to do

Comment: @Raphioly-San ok i understand the problem..need to format year-month from input using php date_format() function

Comment: Searching between a year and month is, surprisingly, quite a complex query. Better solution is to let your programming language find the outer bounds and use those in your query... Or add another field that stores the year-month combination, so you can make your query easy. There's no shame in having some duplicate data (to an extent) in a record if it speeds up or simplifies your queries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a need to use `EXTRACT` at all in this case. Instead you can try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE added_on BETWEEN '20160601' AND '20170630'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m')` /`EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date)` to achieve `yyyymm`

**Using DATE_FORMAT**

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(added_on,'%Y%m') BETWEEN '201606' AND '201706'
```

---

**Using EXTRACT**

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM added_on) BETWEEN '201606' AND '201706'
```

---

**Without using them**

Add 01 to the first date and 31 to the second date.This represent the first and last days of the month

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE added_on BETWEEN '20160601' AND '20170631'
```

Comment: This one never came to mind, but bear in mind that it can be a *very* slow query on large data sets (= we're talking hundred thousands to millions of rows)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `added_on` ) BETWEEN EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM '201606' ) AND EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM '201706' )
```

'201606' and '201706' should be user input. 
If added_on column datatype is date, write EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM `added_on` )
If not date datatype, just write column name

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query -

```
  SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE added_on BETWEEN   REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(added_on,'-',2),'-','')='201606' AND  REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(added_on,'-',2),'-','')='201706';
```